# socket.io and okhttp3 conflict

Tags: java, android, socket.io, okhttp

I am using okhttp3 in an Android project for networking as well as io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3 for socket.io connection.

The following is an extract from my gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.4'
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
```

However when I run the project the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lokhttp3/Request;Lokhttp3/WebSocketListener;Ljava/util/Random;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/ws/RealWebSocket; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket' appears in /data/data/com.fouadkada.mysioapplicationpoc/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okhttp-ws-3.4.2_208c84938ec045e30eddb95384859b3e594c4d81-classes.dex)
                   at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newWebSocket(OkHttpClient.java:414)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.doOpen(WebSocket.java:78)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:82)
                   at io.socket.thread.EventThread.exec(EventThread.java:55)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.open(Transport.java:77)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.probe(Socket.java:472)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onOpen(Socket.java:485)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onHandshake(Socket.java:526)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:499)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$1000(Socket.java:31)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:313)
                   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:134)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.access$700(Polling.java:17)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling$2.call(Polling.java:124)
                   at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.decodePayload(Parser.java:251)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling._onData(Polling.java:134)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.onData(Polling.java:106)
                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(PollingXHR.java:111)
                   at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have tried the solution suggested here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/337 but with no success

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting in the issues section on the github page of socket.io-client-java, I got an answer which solved the issue.

The solution was to remove dependency on okhttp-ws:3.4.2 so the dependencies block becomes as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.4'
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Socket IO doesn’t support the new websockets API [launched](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/web-sockets-now-shipping-in-okhttp-3-5-463a9eec82d1#.yofk3w12f) in OkHttp 3.5.0.

You’ll need to either send them a pull request to update their implementation to use OkHttp’s new websockets API. Or you can roll back your own code to OkHttp 3.4.1.